# White stuff on mango not leaves

Tags: diseases, mango

Hello…My mangoes have this white cotton puffy substance on the fruit but not the leaves. The leaves are nice and healthy looking.It's  a strange substance that has two appearances. One looks like tiny white specks sitting on the skin. The other is also white, but is larger and looks like fluffy cotton sitting on the skin of the mango.

Wiping this stuff comes off and leaves almost no indication it was there except on some mangoes, slight discoloration on the skin where I brushed it off. Any ideas what it is?

Don’t think it’s powdery mildew as the leaves are ok and the fruit develops normally. I can upload pics if needed.

Comment: You described mealy bugs with their very white fluffy material. They don't like soapy water.

Comment: Ahhhh..thanks a lot!!!…maybe I’ll spray soapy water on them and see what happens…appreciate your input..it’s a start!